# Is it ok to make http calls from a Rails Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, activerecord, model-view-controller, architecture

I'm working in an integration between my system and an external webservice. In my system, I have a `Customer` model. A customer, can be in debit, but this information (the customer's financial situation) isn't available in my database. It is in the webservice that I'm integrating with.

I created a method in this model and named it as `is_in_debit?`. In the method implementation, I'm making a HTTP call to the Webservice.

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def is_in_debit?
    response = HTTP.get_response('https://...').body
    response = JSON.parse(response)

    response['status'] == 'active' ? false : true
  end
end
```

But I'm in doubt if the model is the right place to make a HTTP call. From the view point of architecture, is it right? Or should I change my approach?

Comment: Is ok - yes, no, depends. Its usually a better idea to create service objects or some sort of client as models in rails already have so many responsibilities crammed into them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are violating the [SRP principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), in a active record model you should add only methods that access to model data.
I suggest to create a new object:

```
class CustomerService
  def is_in_debit?(user)
     // your http request here
  end
end
```